# Perl regex, grabbing text between tags

Tags: regex, perl

I have a large file that looks something like this:

```
<Feed stack_overflow>
   sourceid 32456
   prefeed 1
   <LOG>
     level 1
     cache info
  </LOG>
</Feed>
```

I want to do a search for anything in this file, and retrieve everything included the Feed tags. So if i do a search for 32456 i will get everything in the code above.

The code i have now is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $input = "<Feed stack_overflow"; #Search string
my $end = "</Feed>"; #End string
open (DATA, "file.config") or die "Error";

my @list = grep /\b$input\b(.*?)\b$end\b/, <DATA>;
chomp @list;
print "$_\n foreach @list;
```

But i don't get any results, even tough I know what i search for exist.
I have successfully managed to print out every line containing a specific string with this regex:

```
my @list = grep /\b$input\b/, <DATA>;
```

But i need help on printing out everything between two tags.

Comment: I would suggest an XML parser such as this: https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Parser

Comment: is your data XML, or does it just look like it?

Comment: @mirod it just looks like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regular expression works with the data line by line, but your string spans over several lines. You can use the [range operator](http://p3rl.org/perlop#Range-Operators):

```
while (<$DATA>) {
    print if /$input/ .. /$end/;
}
```

If you want to exclude the border lines, you can change the inner line to

```
print if (/$input/ .. /$end/) !~ /^1$|E0/}
```

DATA is a predefined file handle. Consider using a different name, or use a lexical file handle (as `$DATA` in my example).

Comment: I can't get this to work. It compiles but does not return any results.

Comment: You have to change your `open` to `open my $DATA, '<', 'file.config' or die $!;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $input = "<Feed stack_overflow"; #Search string
my $end = "</Feed>"; #End string
open (DATA, "file.config") or die "Error";

undef $/; # slurp mode
$_=<DATA>;
close DATA;

@list = m/\b$input\b(.*?)\b$end\b/mg;
map { print "found : $_\n" } @list;
```

(several edits due to errors in the original code)